# Application of Borel Cantelli Lemma in Homework Problem

Tags: probability

I have a homework problem which I encounter some difficulty in. I sincerely hope you all can advise me in proceeding the steps.

I am supposed to construct a sequence of real valued independent random variables $X_1, X_2,..$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n < \infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(X_n)=\infty$, where $E(X_n)$ is the expectation of $X_n$.

I construct the random variables as follows:
$$P(X_n=n)={1\over{n^2}}$$
$$P(X_n=0)=1-{1\over{n^2}}$$ 
In this way, the summation of the expectations will be the standard divergent harmonic series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over{n}}$$

Using Borel Cantelli Lemma, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^2}< \infty$, which means $P(\left\{X_n=n\right\}$ occurs infinitely many times$)=0$.

On the other hand, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1-{1 \over n^2}}= \infty$, which means $P(\left\{X_n=0\right\}$ occurs infinitely many times$)=1$.

Now I know that almost surely, $X_n=0$ infinitely many times. However, how do I make it that the tail sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ equal to $0$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n<\infty$?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You have that $X_n=0$ for all $n$ past a certain $N$ since $P(X_n=n)$ i.o. is zero and your r.v. only takes $0,n$ as possible values. Past this $N$, the tail will be $0$.

Comment: Hi. Is it something like I move the infinitely many $X_n$ that is equal to $0$ backwards so that for all $n$ past a certain $N$, $X_n=0$, therefore making the tail sum $0$. For $n$ before $N$ which finitely many $X_n$s are involved, $X_n$ either assumes the value $0$ or $n$. Hence the total summation will be finite?

Answer (score 0):

With probability $1/n^2, X_n=n$. The Borel-Cantelli lemma tells you that this can only happen a finite amount of time. It could be $5,100,34934$ or $2904904838309$ times, the point is there exist a (finite) value $N$ for which $X_n=0$ for all $n> N$. You do not move the $X_n$ that are null to the end, they get there naturally. You can then write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n=\sum_{n=1}^NX_n+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty X_n.
$$
The first sum on the RHS is finite, it is at most $\sum_{n=1}^N n=N(N+1)/2$, and the second sum is $0$, thus your sum is bounded by $N(N+1)/2<\infty$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Oh. Perhaps it is due to my misinterpretation of the meaning of Borel Cantelli Lemma that lead me into thinking of shifting the nulls back. You are right to say that after a finite number of appearances of $X_n=n$, there will be no $X_n=n$ anymore and the rest will be $X_n=0$. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: You are welcome